# Algorithm for choosing the number of clusters when using pam in R?

Tags: r, clustering, model-selection

I am clustering a dataset using the pam command (from {cluster} package), and I wish to decide on the number of clusters to use.

I was able to implement The_Elbow_Method in R ([see wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set#The_Elbow_Method)) for doing that.  But that doesn't provide me with any solid criteria (like AIC, [for example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set#Information_Criterion_Approach)) for decision.

I came by the {clValid} package which looks promising, but I wanted to know if there are **any other R solutions (you know of) for choosing the number of clusters for pam?**

Here's some dummy code if someone wants to show examples:

```
data(iris)
head(iris)
require(cluster)
pam(iris[,1:4], 3)
```

Comment: I came across a package recently that is supposed to help with this and they reference using it with pam. I haven't tried it yet but it looks promising. Check out the vignette. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clues/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find an [answer to a similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/723/how-can-i-test-whether-my-clustering-of-binary-data-is-significant/749#749) useful. I have also used clValid but, as I recall, it was rather slow (at least for relatively large datasets).

Comment: @Tal Galili You are welcome Tal! If you find out some other method for choosing the number of clusters, share it with us.

Answer (score 4):

The [fpc package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fpc/index.html) provides a few clustering statistics.  If you're looking for information criteria in particular, the `cluster.stats` method provides an information based distance.  For mixture models based on clustering, the BIC is available.

Comment: fpc also has pamk, which can detect the number of clusters.

Answer (score 3):

What about [silhouette](http://bm2.genes.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_current/library/cluster/html/silhouette.html)?

Comment: pam actually gives that out of the box (when using plot on the pam).  I'm still open for other solutions :)

Comment: @Tal I know, but you haven't mentioned it.

Comment: True, I simply forgot:  +1  :)

Comment: Also I still think that this is a very good method.