# Estimate Epsilon in DBSCAN with k-nearest neighbor algorithm

Tags: clustering, distance-functions, k-nearest-neighbour, dbscan

Following [DBSCAN paper](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/KDD/1996/KDD96-037.pdf) (quote below), I'm trying to develop a simple heuristic to determine the parameter Epsilon with K-nearest neighbors (k-NN) algorithm.

> For a given k we define a function k-dist from the database D to the real numbers, mapping each point to the distance from its k-th
> nearest neighbor.

This [tutorial](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-to-implement-k-nearest-neighbors-in-python-from-scratch/) shows a k-NN implementation in Python: before writing it in C, I noticed that all his elements belonging to the dataset always have `n` features/values.

So, while all his elements in his dataset are like this:

> 5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
>
> 4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
>
> 4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa

my current dataset is something like this:

> 0, 245.2300, 101.0000
>
> 0, 13.0000, 10.1000, 23.0000, 14.0000, 32.0000, 21.0000
>
> 0, 25.2300

My dataset is stored in a `double **` matrix: I'd store the dataset above like this:

> [0] [245.2300] [101.0000] [0]       [0]       [0]       [0]
>
> [0] [13.0000]  [10.1000]  [23.0000] [14.0000] [32.0000] [21.0000]
>
> [0] [25.2300]  [0]        [0]       [0]       [0]       [0]

zeroes fill the "missing" values in others points.

In the tutorial the distance between two points is calculated as follows:

```
def euclideanDistance(instance1, instance2, length):
distance = 0
for x in range(length):
    distance += pow((instance1[x] - instance2[x]), 2)
return math.sqrt(distance)
```

but both `instance1` and `instance2` points have 4 features, while my points may have 1, 10 or 1000 features.

Does my representation via matrix filled with zeroes afflict the calculation of `euclideanDistance`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On such data, Euclidean distance does not make sense.

Consider you have two users. for one you know its longitude and latitude,  for the other only the longitude. There is absolutely no good reason to use 0 as missing latitude!

First solve the problem how to get a **good** distance on your data? Then attempt any clustering. Right now,  your result is random garbage.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance in this matter, but I have no idea how to choose a good distance function in DBSCAN for my dataset: I was reading about Euclidean, Manhattan and Canberra distance formulas but I don't know which criteria I should see to choose between them.

Comment: It is *very* much dependant on your data set. We don't know your data - there is little we can help you. With data like you showed above **you will have to *build* a good one yourself**, none of the standard distances will work well on such data!

Comment: Just like feature engineering and data normalization, constructing a good distance measure is a very important task on its own.

Comment: Yes, the shape of my dataset is like above: each row has a variable number of features, looking more like a comb than a decent square matrix.
What would be the best thing do, fix my data so I can get a square matrix without all those zeroes in the first column or write my own distance function?

Comment: Fitting your data into square form gains you nothing, unless you do this in a *meaninful* way. Which depends on what your data *means*, not what it looks like. If you have a list of product IDs, there is no way you can meaningfully squeeze this into a square matrix, end of the story. Make your data make *sense*.

Comment: So my data has no meaning and I have to create my own distance function: thank you, I'll start reading somewhere.

Comment: You have to know what your data contains? Seen on the iris data, each attribute is a physical measurement in mm. On such data, Euclidean distance has a meaning. It is a squared error deviation. But on your data, how would *we* know what is a good similarity?