# Comparing different linkage methods in hierarchical clustering

Tags: unsupervised-learning, hierarchical-clustering

Im trying different linkage methods for my hierarchical clustering problem. Now I would like to evaluate which one works better. Is this as easy as just just comparing the two Dunn's index values? Or should I take other factors into consideration?

Comment: Which linkage methods are you using? This is valuable information when it comes to suggestions for comparison methods.

Comment: Im using single - and complete linkage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select a clustering method? How to validate a cluster solution (to warrant the method choice)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195456/how-to-select-a-clustering-method-how-to-validate-a-cluster-solution-to-warran)

Answer (score 0):

Dunn's index is the ratio of minimum inter-cluster distance to maximum cluster diameter found. As such it is a good measure to compare the two methods. 
The one thing to look out for with Dunn's index is if one cluster is particularly large while all others are compact, then the metric will be misleadingly low.

Other metrics to consider could be:

- within clusters sum of squares
- between clusters sum of squares