# Difference between Ward hierarchical clustering and K-Means for classification

Tags: classification, k-means, hierarchical-clustering, ward

I have a dataset where of socio-demographic features of a population (expressed as percentages over the total population of the municipality: e.g. 12% of freelancers, 5% of unemployed etc.), each observation is a municipality of the city. My goal is to politically classify each municipality in left/right (roughly). I compare both K-Means and hierarchical clustering using the Ward method, and I find that the latter performs way better, misclassifying only 2% of the points, while kmeans does a little worse, with a 6% of wrong points.

My question is: from a theoretical pov, how do I interpret this result? Why should one perform better than another in such a situation?

Comment: Both share the same objective function but the algorithm is very different. In majority of cases k-means, being iterative, will minimize the objective (SSW) somewhat better than Ward. On the other hand, Ward is more apt to "uncover" clusters not so round or not so similar diameter as k-means typically tends for.

Comment: Clustering is not supervised classification. The notion of "miscassification" in clustering isn't a direct test, it is one of facets of external validation. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/195481/3277

Comment: Thanks! I have to say that I already read that answer of yours, which is brilliant, and which is what actually made me wonder things. I surely am in case 4, where "how accurately your clustering method is able to uncover the real clusters is the measure of external validity". BUT: now that I know this, that the Ward clustering performs better on my data, is there a formal way to try explaining why it does?

Comment: Since it is data-dependent, and the results of Ward is even more data dependent than k-means, I'm not sure it is easy to explain theoretically. But try first to do k-means after Ward, using cluster centres of the Ward clusters as initial for k-means - to see if k-means can much improve the results (1) in terms of SSW, (2) in terms of extermal validation (i.e. misclassification). If it improves on (1) but worsen on (2) you may attribute the finding to that - as I've said initially - Ward is less demanding, more permissive in terms of cluster shape/size assumptions.

Comment: Do you perform the two clusterings using the same distance measure?

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that K-means is an insufficient method that was developed for adding machines and is now outdated. I justified this in detail in my article "Reclassification formula that provides to surpass K-means method" (2012) in arXiv.
Ward's clustering combined with advanced K-means (so called, K-meanless method) provides the accurate  optimal clustering with the lowest possible approximation error for each cluster number. This is true, at least for digital images I work with.
M. Kharinov

Answer (score 0):

(1) K-means and Ward's method can be seen as different approaches for optimising the same objective function (within cluster sum of squares, WSS). The performance of K-means regarding WSS depends on the exact algorithm used (there is more than one) and on the initialisation of the algorithm. As most K-means algorithms depend on the initialisation, if some kind of random initialisation is used, this should be done many times and not just once, and the best solution should be used. The question doesn't say which exact algorithm was used and whether enough initialisations were used. Neither is it clear whether the WSS found by K-means is better than that of Ward's method here (if Ward's WSS is better, K-means can be improved running more initialisations).

(2) There is no unique objectively best clustering of a data set. The fact that you have some other categorical (class) variable available such as political orientation doesn't mean that this defined the "best" or uniquely "true" clustering. There can be other meaningful clusterings in the data, even though you don't have the information a priori what they mean (usually cluster analysis is unsupervised which means that we do not assume we know how the clustering we look for is related to external information). This in particular means that using misclassification rate as performance measure is *relative* to the specific "true" classification. A method that looks good regarding one given meaningful clustering can be worse using another one. Clustering is not supervised classification, and it will not use a given class label, so you cannot expect that any given class label not used by the method will be reproduced well. As what you treat as "true classification" is not defined in a mathematical manner, there cannot be any theory that can say why K-means or Ward's method or any other clustering method should be expected to perform "better" here. In particular it is not clear in general, and will depend on subject matter expert knowledge and in particular knowledge of the set of variables used for clustering, whether and why the "true" classification could be expected to yield a low WSS.

(3) That said, Ward's method has been found in a number of comparative studies to often perform rather well (again relative to the clusterings that were declared as "true" there). One difference between Ward's method and K-means is that Ward imposes a clustering hierarchy on the data. Even though Ward will often yield a worse WSS (if K-means is initialised often enough), it may be that the hierarchical structure supports finding clusterings that we tend to find meaningful. This however is not a mathematical or statistical result, rather mere speculation.