# Comparing clustering stability over period of time

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-mining, k-means

Suppose I am applying K-means clustering on two datasets generated by same process. How to compare clustering stability over a period of time? Let's say I have applied clustering in 2016 on a data set, and I want have applied  clustering on a dataset generated by same process in 2017. How to be sure that clusters have not changed/ they are stable ? More specifically , how do I know cluster 1 in 2016 is same as cluster 1 in 2017?

Comment: See point 5 [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/195456/3277) and the many links in the comment to that question.