# How to automatically choose the optimal number of clusters for a hierarchical clustering dendrogram? (R or Python)

Tags: r, python, clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I have a product substitutability matrix, where each cell has a number between 0 and 1 to represent how substitutable (i.e. how similar) the two products are.

I then apply hierarchical clustering to this data in order to create a dendrogram. R code seen below:

```
# turn subs data into a 'matrix' with product 1 on rows, product 2 on columns and subs score in the body
subs_matrix <- reshape(subs_scores, idvar = "p1_name", timevar = "p2_name", direction = "wide")

#Removes the ID's as the rownames and replaces with the product 1 name column
subs_matrix <- subs_matrix %>% remove_rownames %>% column_to_rownames(var="p1_name")

#Removes the column prefix so the row/column names match
colnames(subs_matrix) <- gsub("subs_score.", "", colnames(subs_matrix))

#reverses the subs scores so that lower is more substitutable and orders the rows/columns the same way
subs_matrix<-1-subs_matrix[rownames(subs_matrix),rownames(subs_matrix)]

#put the matrix through the hierarchical clustering method, using ward as the link
c1 <- hclust(as.dist(subs_matrix), method = "ward.D2") #ward.D2

#scale the branches of the tree, only changes the aesthetics the dendrogram for interpretation
min_height<-min(c1$height) - 0.01 #Ensure tree has some height at its lowest point
max_height<-max(c1$height)
c1$height <- (c1$height-min_height)/(max_height-min_height)

#plot the tree, cex is the label font size and hang = -1 roots the branches
plot(c1,cex = 0.6, hang = -1)
```

I have been using this dendrogram to visually identify clusters, and then clusters within the clusters, in order to understand product groupings.

The process of manually identifying the clusters is time consuming, as I have dozens of matrices I need to do this to, so I'm looking for a method to automatically identify a sensible number of clusters, even if the method is imperfect. I could then use that number as my k value in a function such as `cuttree` in R, and re-apply this method to find more clusters, within each cluster.

The best tool I've found for this seems to be NbClust in R:

```
library(NbClust)

diss = as.dist(subs_matrix)

nb.fit <- NbClust(diss, min.nc = 2, max.nc = 12, method = 'ward.D2', index = 'all')

nb.fit["Best.nc"]
```

This uses 26 different methods to pick the optimal number of clusters, and then picks the modal result. Unfortunately, I usually get this error when running it:

```
Error in solve.default(W) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 6.00125e-17
```

My understanding of the mathematics isn't great, but this apparently arises because the matrix is not invertible, which apparently is likely because some of the columns of my matrix are correlated. I don't know how this can be fixed, as often I will be comparing some very similar products, which will likely have highly correlated substitutability scores.

I also found an automated way to get a number of clusters using the elbow method, but this number always seemed weird, and didn't match what could be seen in the dendrogram.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to get the number of clusters in an automated way? Is it possible I should be using a different clustering methodology altogether, rather than hierarchical clustering? All help is much appreciated. I have code for the hierarchical clustering in both R and Python, so I could use a solution in either language.

Comment: What do you mean by "an automated way"? For some general guidelines to select a better cluster solution, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/195481/3277). As for the error you cite, it is a specific topic perhaps confined to a specific criterion - maybe try to contact with the package authors.

Comment: I mean I want code which returns a number, and that number is a reasonable choice for the number of clusters. I don't want a chart or anything which I need to manually interpret in order to pick the number of clusters