# Gap statistics MATLAB implementation

Tags: clustering, matlab, mathematical-statistics

Does any know the reference/link where i can find the MATLAB implementation of gap statistics for clustering as mentioned in [this](http://gremlin1.gdcb.iastate.edu/MIP/gene/MicroarrayData/gapstatistics.pdf) paper?

Comment: Please, don't cross-post on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241181/gap-statistics-matlab-implementation) and [MatlabCentral](http://www.mathworks.fr/matlabcentral/answers/8811-gap-staticstics-implementation)!

Comment: The gap statistic takes 20 lines of code or less to implement. It may be faster just to write it yourself.

Comment: @chi ok will not repeat the same.

Answer (score 3):

The Statistics Toolbox [implements the gap statistic](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/clustering.evaluation.gapevaluation-class.html) as a class in the package `clustering.evaluation` since R2013b:

```
load fisheriris;
rng('default');  % For reproducibility
eva = evalclusters(meas,'kmeans','gap','KList',[1:6])
figure;
plot(eva);
```

[image]

You can also use this [file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37905-gap-statistics).

Comment: +1. I always have a sweet-spot for question archaeologists. On another note, R2013b seems to have really invested in the Stats toolbox functionality. I also saw a first *actually usable* LME implementation.

Comment: The file linked does not produce the same graph for the same data set. It recommends two clusters, rather than 4 on R2011a.

Comment: Well one of them is wrong or use some variant as the algorithm to compute the gap is supposed to be deterministic :)